Update hierarchical columns with primary key value when they are null
I have a table like:



id
parentId
rootId




1
1
1


2
2
2



When I insert a new row that will be a root (eg. parentId and rootId = id), i need a trigger to update parentId and rootId with the value of "id" (autoincrementing primary key)
However, I can't seem to update the inserted row with and AFTER INSERT trigger and I can't seem to reference the value of ID with a BEFORE INSERT trigger.
I'm using 10.6.16-MariaDB-log

MyPHP

Attempt  #1
Result: "Updating of NEW row not allowed in AFTER trigger"
CREATE TRIGGER xxx AFTER INSERT ON TBL_COMMENTS
FOR EACH ROW
BEGIN
    IF NEW.parentCommentId IS NULL THEN 
       SET NEW.parentCommentId = NEW.id, NEW.rootCommentId = NEW.id;
    END IF;
END

Attempt  #2
Result: No error, but parent/root key not updated
CREATE TRIGGER xxx BEFORE INSERT ON TBL_COMMENTS
FOR EACH ROW
BEGIN
    IF NEW.parentCommentId IS NULL THEN 
       SET NEW.parentCommentId = NEW.id, NEW.rootCommentId = NEW.id;
    END IF;
END

I've tried a wide variety of other methods but can't seem to get it to work

In my understanding, a "hierarchy" has only one "root". Please explain what it means in your universe to have two different values in the rootid column.  (cf ysth's answer)

You can't use auto increment columns in a trigger that way, but you can use a column that defaults from a sequence:
create sequence TBL_COMMENTS_id;
create table TBL_COMMENTS (id int not null default nextval(TBL_COMMENTS_id) primary key, parentCommentId int, rootCommentId int);
delimiter $$
CREATE TRIGGER xxx BEFORE INSERT ON TBL_COMMENTS
FOR EACH ROW
BEGIN
    IF NEW.parentCommentId IS NULL THEN 
       SET NEW.parentCommentId = NEW.id, NEW.rootCommentId = NEW.id;
    END IF;
END
$$
delimiter ;
insert into TBL_COMMENTS () values ();
select * from TBL_COMMENTS;

+----+-----------------+---------------+
| id | parentCommentId | rootCommentId |
+----+-----------------+---------------+
|  1 |               1 |             1 |
+----+-----------------+---------------+


In my understanding, a "hierarchy" has only one "root".  Please explain what it means in your universe to have two different values in the rootid column.

@RickJames maybe you were asking the OP, but anyway, if there is one root, it is a tree.  if multiple roots, it is called a forest  https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tree_%28graph_theory%29   and the existence of the rootCommentId (as well as the nature of "comments") imply that this is a forest

This solution worked, so many thanks! Greatly appreciated :)
@RickJames I think the answer by "ysth" is better than any I could give but for specific context on what I'm doing, any top level comment is itself a root. Descendent comments then take on that initial rootId as the parentId and the rootId. Descendents to those comments then persist the rootId but take the level above as the parentId (and so on...).
Hopefully you see how this structure works now!

do note you will need to change any use of LAST_INSERT_ID to lastval(TBL_COMMENTS_id)
